# Windows public kiosk

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-chrome, windows-10

I have a public kiosk with windows OS and wifi connection. It will be running a fullscreen browser. There will not be any physical keyboard or mouse, only touchscreen and onscreen keyboard. Here are some of the criteria I can't quite figure out:

1) Disable/hide the URL bar, back, close, home, download or any navigation buttons **on the** browser application. (I understand that chrome kiosk mode can do this)

2) If the user attempts to leave the webpage they will be redirected back to the webpage. (no idea how yet, but if they dont have back/home button, I cant use some of the whitelist apps on chrome because they would throw a 404 and the browser will be stuck without a way to proceed or go back)

3) User can navigate within the designated webpage say *hello.website.com* or *website.com/info.html* but not *otherwebsite.com/nope*

I am open to suggestions, it does not have to be chrome.

Comment: You might use something like SiteKiosk http://www.sitekiosk.com/web/us/products/windows-kiosk-software-sitekiosk

Comment: Disabling the back and home buttons seems counterproductive -- they seem like they would be a useful way of letting users escape from unintended situations.

Comment: @duskwuff I understand where youre coming from regarding disabling back and home button. I was hoping for the best course of action with the least user input, I can imagine showing a 404 or having to click home to get out of sticky situations might not be the best option for a public kiosk, which should be as automated(idiot proof) as possible.

ChrisRiebschlager thank you! looking into this right now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript to disable keys, on your webpage you can use the following script. Also to know the keys go to http://www.heckdesigns.com/tutorials/tutorial-disabling-keyboard-keys-with-javascript/ in order to learn all of the keys.

Also, for your second and third question, you can just make the mac fullscreen by pressing the 3 dots to the top right corner of your browser. Then go fullscreen, it's on 'zoom' settings. This will take out the navigation bar and tools to go to another page. This is important since 2) and 3) are more complicated to achieve.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BySHl.png)

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
if (key == 8 || key == 48 || key == 49 || key == 50 || key == 51  || key == 
52 || key == 53 || key == 54 || key == 65 || key == 56 || key == 57 || key 
== 58) {
} else {
e.preventDefault();
}      
}
</script>
<input />
<p>Try pressing the number pad and the backspace keys, they are enabled, unlike the other keys. This will not work here so I recommend you doing this in a new HTML page</p>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Please read it completely before writing an answer.

Comment: I'm working on it (really sorry for my action) it wont happen again